# Why is the dropdown not displaying after changing the jquery select2 plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2, metronic

It is using Metronic 8 theme. I am editing the multi-steps-sign-up.html page. The account type that needs to be newly created is two. If the Checkbox is selected, the number of steps needs to be changed. I have succeeded but the contents also need to be changed according to the steps. I provide this with jquery clone(), remove() and then after(). But when after() re-adds the content, select2 cannot display the selectbox dropdown. The code file I edited (create-account.js);

```
"use strict";
var KTCreateAccount = function() {
    var e, t, i, o, a, r, s = [];
    var chkbx;
    var client;
    var writer;
    var acc_type;
    var frm_step;
    var numberx;
    var fivehtml;
    var fourhtml;
    var fourinhtml;

    return {
        init: function() {
            (e = document.querySelector("#kt_modal_create_account")) && new bootstrap.Modal(e),
            (t = document.querySelector("#kt_create_account_stepper")) && (i = t.querySelector("#kt_create_account_form"),
            o = t.querySelector('[data-kt-stepper-action="submit"]'),
            a = t.querySelector('[data-kt-stepper-action="next"]'),
            (r = new KTStepper(t)).on("kt.stepper.changed", (function(e) {
                numberx == r.getCurrentStepIndex() ? (o.classList.remove("d-none"),
                o.classList.add("d-inline-block"),
                a.classList.add("d-none")) : frm_step == r.getCurrentStepIndex() ? (o.classList.add("d-none"),
                a.classList.add("d-none")) : (o.classList.remove("d-inline-block"),
                o.classList.remove("d-none"),
                a.classList.remove("d-none"))
            }
            )),
            $(window).on("load", function() {
                client = (document.querySelector('#kt_create_account_form_account_type_personal')),
                writer = (document.querySelector('#kt_create_account_form_account_type_corporate')),
                acc_type = [client, writer],
                fivehtml = $("[data-kt-stepper-element='content']:eq(-1)").clone();
                fourinhtml = $("[data-kt-stepper-element='content']:eq(-2)").clone();
                fourhtml = $(".stepper-item:eq(-2)").clone();
                chkbx = (client.checked) ? "client" && (frm_step = 4) && $(".stepper-item:eq(-2)").remove() && $(".stepper-item:eq(-1)").find(".stepper-number").html("4") && $("[data-kt-stepper-element='content']:eq(-2)").remove() : (writer.checked) ? "writer" && (frm_step = 5) && $(".stepper-item:eq(-2)").after(fourhtml) && $(".stepper-item:eq(-1)").find(".stepper-number").html("5") && $("[data-kt-stepper-element='content']:eq(-2)").after(fourinhtml) : "none";
                numberx = (frm_step == 4) ? 3 : (frm_step == 5) ? 4 : "none",
                acc_type.forEach(radio => {
                    radio.addEventListener('change', () => {
                        chkbx = (client.checked) ? "client" && (frm_step = 4) && $(".stepper-item:eq(-2)").remove() && $(".stepper-item:eq(-1)").find(".stepper-number").html("4") && $("[data-kt-stepper-element='content']:eq(-2)").remove() : (writer.checked) ? "writer" && (frm_step = 5) && $(".stepper-item:eq(-2)").after(fourhtml) && $(".stepper-item:eq(-1)").find(".stepper-number").html("5") && $("[data-kt-stepper-element='content']:eq(-2)").after(fourinhtml) : "none";
                        numberx = (frm_step == 4) ? 3 : (frm_step == 5) ? 4 : "none";
                        numbery = 1;
                        
                    })
                  });
            }),
            r.on("kt.stepper.next", (function(e) {
                console.log("stepper.next");
                var t = s[e.getCurrentStepIndex() - 1];
                t ? t.validate().then((function(t) {
                    console.log("validated!"),
                    "Valid" == t ? (e.goNext(),
                    KTUtil.scrollTop()) : Swal.fire({
                        text: "Sorry, looks like there are some errors detected, please try again.",
                        icon: "error",
                        buttonsStyling: !1,
                        confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                        customClass: {
                            confirmButton: "btn btn-light"
                        }
                    }).then((function() {
                        KTUtil.scrollTop()
                    }
                    ))
                }
                )) : (e.goNext(),
                KTUtil.scrollTop())
            }
            )),
            r.on("kt.stepper.previous", (function(e) {
                console.log("stepper.previous"),
                e.goPrevious(),
                KTUtil.scrollTop()
            }
            )),
            s.push(FormValidation.formValidation(i, {
                fields: {
                    account_type: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Account type is required"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger,
                    bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap5({
                        rowSelector: ".fv-row",
                        eleInvalidClass: "",
                        eleValidClass: ""
                    })
                }
            })),
            s.push(FormValidation.formValidation(i, {
                fields: {
                    account_name: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Account name is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    account_plan: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Account plan is required"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger,
                    bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap5({
                        rowSelector: ".fv-row",
                        eleInvalidClass: "",
                        eleValidClass: ""
                    })
                }
            })),
            s.push(FormValidation.formValidation(i, {
                fields: {
                    business_name: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Busines name is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    business_descriptor: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Busines descriptor is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    business_type: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Busines type is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    business_email: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Busines email is required"
                            },
                            emailAddress: {
                                message: "The value is not a valid email address"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger,
                    bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap5({
                        rowSelector: ".fv-row",
                        eleInvalidClass: "",
                        eleValidClass: ""
                    })
                }
            })),
            s.push(FormValidation.formValidation(i, {
                fields: {
                    card_name: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Name on card is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    card_number: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Card member is required"
                            },
                            creditCard: {
                                message: "Card number is not valid"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    card_expiry_month: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Month is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    card_expiry_year: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Year is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    card_cvv: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "CVV is required"
                            },
                            digits: {
                                message: "CVV must contain only digits"
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 3,
                                max: 4,
                                message: "CVV must contain 3 to 4 digits only"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger,
                    bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap5({
                        rowSelector: ".fv-row",
                        eleInvalidClass: "",
                        eleValidClass: ""
                    })
                }
            })),
            o.addEventListener("click", (function(e) {
                s[3].validate().then((function(t) {
                    console.log("validated!"),
                    "Valid" == t ? (e.preventDefault(),
                    o.disabled = !0,
                    o.setAttribute("data-kt-indicator", "on"),
                    setTimeout((function() {
                        o.removeAttribute("data-kt-indicator"),
                        o.disabled = !1,
                        r.goNext()
                    }
                    ), 2e3)) : Swal.fire({
                        text: "Sorry, looks like there are some errors detected, please try again.",
                        icon: "error",
                        buttonsStyling: !1,
                        confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                        customClass: {
                            confirmButton: "btn btn-light"
                        }
                    }).then((function() {
                        KTUtil.scrollTop()
                    }
                    ))
                }
                ))
            }
            )),
            $(i.querySelector('[name="card_expiry_month"]')).on("change", (function() {
                s[3].revalidateField("card_expiry_month")
            }
            )),
            $(i.querySelector('[name="card_expiry_year"]')).on("change", (function() {
                s[3].revalidateField("card_expiry_year")
            }
            )),
            $(i.querySelector('[name="business_type"]')).on("change", (function() {
                s[2].revalidateField("business_type")
            }
            )))
        }
    }
}();
KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded((function() {
    KTCreateAccount.init()
}
));
```

I tried these solutions but without success.

- A few changes to the DOM.
- I read select2 document.

```
$("[name='card_expiry_month']").select2("destroy");
$("[name='card_expiry_year']").select2();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdrsmn14/1/)

Comment: It's not clear what you challenge/question is. Can you pin point what you have tried, where is your modification, or show an example?

Also it will be more practical for you to modify an uncompiled js code. Assuming you're referring to this theme https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/demo1/authentication/extended/multi-steps-sign-up.html and this JS code  https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/demo1/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-account.js

Comment: Please copy your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ and make it workable there so we can test.

Comment: @jjj thanks for your comment. I'd better use uncompiled code, right?

Comment: @MykolaUspalenko As you said my code now includes a jsfiddle example.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/wdrsmn14/1/)

Comment: @app_dev, please press F12 and review errors like:

fiddle.jshell.net/:1 Access to font at 'https://writerarmy.testmode.tk/dist/assets/plugins/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.woff2' from origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Maybe those errors can be ignored.

Comment: @MykolaUspalenko Those errors have nothing to do with the question. In the jsfiddle example the script works as expected. The problem to be solved is that the selectbox option menu in the "Expiration Date" section cannot be displayed in step 4 of the form, after the after() operation.

Comment: suggestion #1.

F12, then in console, select 'result' instead 'top' on the Chrome top menu:

Comment: $("[data-kt-stepper-element='content']:eq(-2)")[0].outerHTML shows a large block.

`<div class="" data-kt-stepper-element="content">\n\t\t\t\t\t\... `
Update .clone() or  $(...html()) , the browser works badly with cloning element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252512/discussion-between-mykola-uspalenko-and-app-dev).